# tp-link 1043nd no internet after flashing to gargoyle firmware

Tags: router, firmware, tp-link

I have recently bought a tp-link wr1043nd version 1.10 and flashed gargoyle firmware 1.5.9 onto it after the intermediate step of flashing from stock firmware to German version of firmware.

I have read that the intermediate step of flashing to the German firmware should preserve the WAN port (prevent the WAN port from being disabled, if other alternative firmwares were installed to the router).

Right now, the gargoyle firmware has been successfully flashed, but no internet!  I believe that the lack of internet is similar to the WAN port being disabled issue that I was trying to prevent.

Any input as to how to revert back to stock firmware? I'm trying very hard to avoid a 'brick'. A link to the appropriate, correct firmware would be appreciated. As would step by step instructions on how to apply this firmware to the router.

---

I'm not very good with technology in general but I'm looking to use some features in third party firmware to:

1. control bandwidth quota per device
2. monitor bandwidth usage as well.

I am also up for suggestions as to new router choices that would be compatible with any of the third party firmwares that offer the 'bandwidth quota control' feature as well as any routers that come with the 'bandwidth quota' feature already straight out of the box!

Comment: This appears to be off topic for Server Fault. Perhaps you meant to post at our sister site [su]? Be sure to check the respective FAQ and About pages prior to posting, to ensure that you are on the right site.

Answer (score 1):

Look on dd-wrt after:

tl_wr1043nd_webrevert.rar
to restore to stock, then

wr1043nv1_de_3_9_17_up_boot(100331).bin
 this for removing te protection
and then reinstall what you want.

Comment: so id need to use the webrevert file  by ddwrt first,
then use the stock firmware from to-link?

will the ddwrt webrevert file work?
because currently, i have gargoyle (openwrt based) flashed on the router already.

that file has the word 'boot', then wont it just disable the WAN port again?(assuming its the provided stock firmware)

is there a stock firmware i can use that doesnt not contain the 'boot' in the file name?

trying hard get the WAN port enabled again..
and trying to avoid a 'brick'

thx for the input! further guidance appreciated.

Comment: First revert to stock;